# Codeship Pro special characters

Tags: curl, continuous-integration, codeship

I'm trying to add a step to a Codeship Pro build that curls a bash script and executes it. So I have the following in my `codeship-steps.yml`

```
- service: my_service   
  command: bash <(curl -s https://url.of.the/script)
```

When I try to run my build (on codeship or via jet) I get the following error output:

```
bash: <(curl: No such file or directory
```

Doing a `jet run` and getting inside my Docker image I can run that command no-problem. [Codeship's instructions](https://documentation.codeship.com/pro/builds-and-configuration/steps/) mention the following:

> Note that quotes are respected to split up arguments, but special characters such as &&, | or > are not.

That seems strangely restrictive. Am I misinterpreting that note and there's something else wrong with my codeship steps, or is there another way to curl and execute a script?

Comment: Are you running this with sudo privileges ?

Comment: read this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124838/process-substitution-from-curl-to-bash-as-root

Comment: and this : http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html